# How to show the map in Photos?

Tags: macos, maps, photos.app

I just upgraded to OS X Yosemite with the new Photos application. I have seen screenshots online where we can view photos on a map, however I can't get to that map.

How can I see *all of my photos* on a map, like in iPhoto/Aperture?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation to add an answer (d'oh!), but the problem with the accepted solution is that the pins on the info panel aren't interactive, therefore this solution not ideal. If you go to "Photos" and click the "BACK" button, you'll eventually come to years. There you can click on the location (e.g. "2015 North America, Europe") and you'll see all images of this year on a map. I haven't found any solution to show all years though.

Comment: @auco That's the same thing as what's in the second part of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For more recent versions of Photos.app (Version 2.0 that came with macOS 10.12 Sierra at least), there is a "Places" item avaialble under "Albums" in the sidebar (use "View" -> "Show Sidebar" if it is not visible). This gives a map view similar to that available in iPhoto.app.

For older versions of Photos.app, it does not appear that there is a way to see ALL photo locations on a map at one time, aside from a small Info window. Here's what you need to do:

**For the small info window that shows all locations:**
 1. Go to the Albums tab in Photos
 2. Right-click on "All Photos" -> Get info
 3. Note the small window has a map included which you can zoom in/out of

**For maps that vary by date:**

1. Go to View menu -> Metadata -> Location
2. Go to the Photos tab and zoom all the way out to Years
3. Note that there are locations next to the year. Click on the location name

Comment: Thank you, I hope they add such feature in the next versions. I was mostly concerned that the "geolocation" concept was going to disappear entirely (I'm a metadata maniac). In the meantime the options you mention are still quite nice (even though limited) and they show that geolocation is still handled by the application.

Comment: @Matthieu I agree. I definitely liked the view, especially on the phone.

Comment: So there's no way to go to an arbitrary location and see what photos you've taken there? You have to start by rummaging for a group of photos that happens to have been taken near the desired location?

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius that seems to be correct. I mean, you can get to the photos on a year-by-year basis, so as long as you knew the year (and not necessarily the location), you could do a holistic map. However, there isn't a whole "Places" feature like there was previously.

Comment: Images will still be limited to a single year though (despite what the UI says), right ?

Comment: I had this question for a long time, and was very happy to learn of the small Info window solution, even if it is limited.  I couldn't quite reproduce it on my computer.  At step 2, Right-click on "All Photos", I didn't get the option to Get info.  Instead, I was able to Select All and then Get Info for the collection, by right-clicking on one of the selected photos.  I had Photos Version 1.5.

Comment: Hello +raxacoricofallapatorius, I'm pretty sure my UI is saying explicitly that the info covers multiple years.   But I'm writing over a year since your comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can type a location into the search box and one of the options usually is a location; if you select it, a map comes up showing all of the photos taken in that location.  For example, if you type 'Colorado' in the search box, 'Colorado - State' is one of the choices.

Comment: Interesting. A bizzare and somewhat silly (and unreliable) substitute but somewhat helpful (when it works). And it has the advantage of not using the astonishingly slow map view, which is something.

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can see all your photos on a map, it is just not obvious. Go to Photos and go all the way out to see all your images. You now see location names for all locations you have tagged your photos with, together with year or year interval. Simply click the location name and a map will be shown.

Comment: "This seems to be the same than the second part of the other answer? I.e. I can see the map for up to a year, but not the one containing all my photos. –  Matthieu Napoli"